# Harvard VS APA: the differences? How about mixing styles for a better clarity?

Tags: citations, citation-style

For a while, I thought that I've been using an APA version of 'Harvard style' but it turned out that these 2 styles are totally different. What are the exact differences and, generally speaking, is mixing between styles a bad practice? (If the intention is for more clarity and the university doesn't ask for a specific style).

Comment: There are at least two questions here, which is discouraged, and the first question is potentially massive. There could be hundreds or thousands of differences between APA and Harvard citation style. Why not pick a piece of software (EndNote or BibTeX) that can automatically implement one of them and just use it? Especially if your venue doesn't actually care.

Comment: Obviously, as @BillBarth mentioned, the _exact differences_ question is too large for an answer on this site. You will have to do your own analysis - the relevant information is trivial to find.

Answer (score 2):

Even if your current university and situation do not call for using a specific publication style, I would strongly recommend against mixing two or more styles, even if they are not much different. The reason is pretty clear: **consistency**. For the sake of *readers* of your publications as well as for the sake of your own *sanity*. Following a single style will make your life easier - if you can choose, just pick the one you feel more *comfortable* with or the one *popular*, or, perhaps, a standard *de facto*, in your field (the latter is IMHO much more important - again, that "for the sake of readers" argument).